# Fullcalendar - drop event on listview

Tags: listview, events, fullcalendar, droppable

I am using the "listMonth" view on my fullcalendar. When I drop an external event on the normal agenda the events 'drop' and 'eventReceive' get triggered, but when I drop an event on the listview it doesn't trigger these events. Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: No because it's just a list of events, not a grid. There's no empty space in between the events on which to drag anything. Use the agenda or basic views for this.

Comment: Thought so, thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not heaps helpful in terms of getting useful data, but if you're looking for a way to detect that an item has been dropped on the calendar, you can use the jQuery droppable stop function.

```
$(".item").draggable({
    //other details
    stop:function(event, ui){
        //get a reference to the calendar
        var calendar = $("#calendar");

        //get bounds
        var bounds = [
            left:calendar.offset().left,
            top:calendar.offset().top,
            width:calendar.width(),
            height:calendar.height()
        ];

        //get coordinates
        var x = event.pageX;
        var y = event.pageY;

        //check if in bounds
        if (
        x >= bounds.left &&
        x <= bounds.left + bounds.width &&
        y >= bounds.top &&
        y <= bounds.top + bounds.height
        ){
            //item has been dropped within
        }
    }
});
```

Unfortunately jQuery doesn't have a way of determining the item you dropped it onto.

Comment: Thanks for the info anyway!